# Вернуть BytesIO как .xlsx файл

Tags: python, bottle

В MySQL BLOB полях записаны файлы MS Excel. Как можно передать пользователю эти данные без промежуточного сохранения? То есть, наверно, с помощью io.BytesIO.

```
# пусть переменная bin_data содержит двоичные данные из ячейки (BLOB) таблицы
buffer = io.Bytes()
buffer.write(bin_data)
```

Затем пользователю в браузер надо передать ссылку или запрос на сохранение файла в формате Excel, содержащего эти данные.

Comment: Что (какую библиотеку) вы используете для передачи?

Comment: Вся эта система - Bottle проект.

Comment: читайте документацию к bottle - вам нужно создать объект HTTPResponse, в качестве тела (body) передать file-like object, ну и заголовки ответа конечно задать (mimetype и т.д.)

Comment: А можно ссылку именно на этот пункт документации.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите, чтобы браузер вместо показа данных загрузил бы их на диск, то можно [послать `Content-Disposition` http заголовок со значением `attachment`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266#section-4.2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from bottle import route, run, response  # fades.pypi

@route('/')
def index():
    response.content_type = (  # set mime type for .xlsx
        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = (
        'attachment; filename=blob.xlsx;'
        " filename*=utf-8''%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1.xlsx")
    return bin_data

run(host='localhost', port=24303)
```

Вот [документация для bottle.response объекта](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#the-response-object).